# what does [ARG.1] mean in ollydbg?

Tags: ollydbg

I am analyzing a program in ollydbg, and some instructions get disassembled as [ARG.1], eg: 
MOV ESI,[ARG.1]

I tried searching for this command in assembly books, but seems as if it's only used in ollydbg and is not a standard assembly code.
am I right?
and what does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect ollydbg is trying to be helpful by reverse engineering your stack layout for you, and that `[ARG.1]` is really `[EBP+0x08]` or the like -- the first argument on the stack if you're in a function called with the C calling convention.

Not having used ollydbg in a while, I'm sure there's a way to convince ollydbg to show you more literally what the exact opcode is.

Answer (score 1):

You can switch off showing ARGs and LOCALs from: Options -> Debugging options -> Analysis 1 -> "Show ARGs and LOCALs in procedures".

Then it's possible to see the real representation of ARGs and LOCALs.

Comment: For OllyDbg 2.x users, the option can be found at Options -> Analysis -> "Show recognized ARGs and LOCALs in disassembly"